# First vault symbol glitch in Wildlife Exploitation Preserve?

Tags: borderlands-2

I'm in Playthrough 1 as Gaige the Mechromancer, if that matters.  I'm jumping on the loading crane trying to ride it over the nearby building to get the first vault symbol, and have died five times in a row.  I wait for the crane to lower, and as it starts rising, I let it clear the force field and jump on.  When I try from the right side of the crane, i.e. I'm between the crane and the target building, I die almost immediately.  I tried that a few times, with the same result each time.

So I switched to the opposite side, and thought I had finally made it because the crane rose and started to turn toward the building, but then the game froze for a second and I was re-spawning!  This happened twice.  After losing almost $20k on this, I thought I'd check to see what's up... has anyone else experienced this problem?  Is this a bug in the latest game update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I linked a youtube video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y7Yz3LOjvwA) where you can see how to reach the first vault symbol.

You have to wait until the crane grabs into the ground and jump on it. When it reaches the top of the building where the vault symbol is, just jump on the roof of the building and it's done.

I hope I was able to help you.

Comment: Thanks, that's basically what I was attempting, just waited briefly for the crane to start rising before jumping on.  I'll see if running onto it immediately makes a difference.

Comment: I can confirm this.  I had to get on on the side farthest from the building, and be on the very edge of the crane before it came out of the ground.  Other side, closer in, or as it was coming out meant death.